# React app not hitting url described in proxy ( package.json file )

Tags: reactjs, express

`"proxy": "http://localhost:3001"` in my package.json
where the express server is running on this port ( 3001 ), but every time I am hitting a request from react it's going on 3000 port on which react app is running

package.json

```
{
  "name": "client",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "antd": "^3.10.2",
    "axios": "^0.18.0",
    "dotenv": "^6.1.0",
    "http-proxy-middleware": "^0.19.0",
    "material-ui": "^0.20.2",
    "react": "^16.5.2",
    "react-bootstrap": "^0.32.4",
    "react-dom": "^16.5.2",
    "react-form": "^3.5.6",
    "react-redux": "^5.0.4",
    "react-router-dom": "^4.3.1",
    "react-router-redux": "^5.0.0-alpha.5",
    "react-scripts": "2.0.5",
    "styled-components": "^4.0.2"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": "react-app"
  },
  "browserslist": [
    ">0.2%",
    "not dead",
    "not ie <= 11",
    "not op_mini all"
  ]
}
```

setupProxy.js

```
const proxy = require('http-proxy-middleware');

module.exports = function(app) {
  app.use(proxy('/api/*', { target: 'http://localhost:3001' }));
};
```

Comment: in your index.js define const PORT = process.env.PORT || 3001;

Answer (score 0):

You can define the port in your index.js

```
const PORT = 3001;
```

and use

```
"proxy": { "/*": { "target": "http://localhost:3001" } }
```

in client package.json

for http-proxy-middleware:
install the package.
create a file called setupProxy.js
and inside it use below pattern

```
const proxy = require('http-proxy-middleware');

module.exports = function(app) {
  app.use(proxy('/', { target: 'http://localhost:3001' }));
};
```

Remember to remove the old proxy scripts code from your client side package.json .

Comment: Isn't this method in express to define port which it should use. My express is already running on 3001 but the request i am sending from react is not hitting on 3001 but on  its own port of 3000. My problem is that proxy not working in react app

Comment: you trying to connect using http-proxy-middleware ?

Comment: Yea  i am not able to use proxy in object format and get this error:                     When specified, "proxy" in package.json must be a string.
Instead, the type of "proxy" was "object".

Comment: What`s the node and npm version you use. For latest better if you could use http-proxy-middleware package

Comment: Npm 6.4.1 & node 10.8.0

Comment: installed http-proxy-middleware on reactjs side and created new file setupProxy.js with following code:`const proxy = require('http-proxy-middleware');
    module.exports = function(app) {
    app.use(proxy('/api', 
                   { target: 'http://localhost:3001/' }
      ));
    }`     still no success

Comment: have you restarted the servers?

Comment: yes... restarted both react and express but still no success.

Comment: could you add the package.json file and setupProxy.js in src (react side) to your question

Comment: I have updated question with files. got anything. i am stuck.. otherwise i'll have to create a new app with react

Comment: have you removed all the tryouts to fix previous proxy issues. If there are proxy setings you`ve done to previous issues, it might give the same error message

Comment: I only used method of proxy in package.json, nothing else was done. after that i added http-proxy-middleware

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/182985/discussion-between-brjava-and-kshitij).

Answer (score 0):

```
"proxy": {
"/services": {
  "target": "http://localhost:3001",
  "changeOrigin": true,
  "pathRewrite": {
    "^/services": ""
  }
}
```

}

*npm start again*

Comment: Yea  i am not able to use proxy in object format and get this error:                     When specified, "proxy" in package.json must be a string.
Instead, the type of "proxy" was "object".

Answer (score 0):

If you are using new version http-proxy-middleware ("1.X.X"), the code could be changed to the following:

```js
const { createProxyMiddleware } = require('http-proxy-middleware');

module.exports = function(app) {
  app.use('/console/api', createProxyMiddleware({ 
    target: 'http://localhost:8080/', 
    changeOrigin: true, 
    pathRewrite: {'^/console/api' : ''} 
  }));
};
```

In other words, `proxy` should be replaced with `createProxyMiddleware`